# Formatting bookdown theorem environment titles (e.g, example) using (ref:foo)

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, bookdown

The [advice in `bookdown` for formatting long figure captions and other text is to create a reference](https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/markdown-extensions-by-bookdown.html#text-references),

```
(ref:foo) Title with _formatting_.
```

With a blank line above and below, and then referring to this in the figure caption.

I'm not getting this to work for [theorem environments](https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/markdown-extensions-by-bookdown.html#tab:theorem-envs) like `example`, however, when knitting to pdf.

Reproducible example:

````
---
title: "Table test"
output:
  bookdown::pdf_document2:
    keep_tex: true
---

# Test

(ref:foo) This is a test.

```{exercise revision1, echo = T, name="(ref:foo)"}
Some exercise description. 
```
````

When knitted as a pdf:

```
rmarkdown::render("test.rmd")
```

Results in,

```
Exercise 1.1 ((ref:foo)). Some exercise description.
```

Comment: Could you show us the YAML section of your file? I think you need to set `output: bookdown::pdf_document2`.

Answer (score 0):

[This is a bug](https://github.com/rstudio/tufte/issues/75) in **bookdown** that I [just fixed](https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown/commit/826076b22d16e56528e0ef82feeeba882ba9aa05) on Github. For now, you may try the development version of **bookdown**:

```r
remotes::install_github(c('yihui/knitr', 'rstudio/bookdown'))
```